# How to include asio boost in cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, boost-asio, static-libraries, cmake-language

I'm trying to include `asio boost` using `CMake`in my project but I'm getting this error. libraries linking is working in `VS` but I don't know how to link them in `Cmake` project.

***Working Solution with VS:-***

`asio boost version: 1.24.0`

[VS ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxi3D.png)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(networking_examples)

#set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER D:/System/msys2/mingw64/bin/clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Link Boost Asio library
target_include_directories(networking_examples PRIVATE "./asio-1.24.0/include")

add_executable(
  networking_examples
  ./src/index.cpp
)
```

[CMake Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5gOB.png)

> I want to link `./asio-1.24.0/include`   with my project using `CMAKE`.

**Error:**

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "networking_examples" which
  is not built by this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Git Repo/c++/networking/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `target_include_directories` there is not target named `networking_examples`. You add that target *after*.

Order matters, and just like in C++ symbols must be defined before they can be used.

So you need to change to:

```
add_executable(
  networking_examples
  ./src/index.cpp
)

# Asio library header directory
target_include_directories(networking_examples PRIVATE "./asio-1.24.0/include")
```

---

On another couple of notes: First you don't seem to be using Boost ASIO but rather the standalone header-only library.

Secondly, you don't *link* with the library (it's a *header-only* library). You only tell the build-system where it can find the ASIO header files.